# How Deny Visual Studio compile any files?

Tags: asp.net-core, bower, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 is compiling files present in bower folder and show errors about that, how avoid compile this folder?

Answer (score 0):

right click, properties then you can choose how the file is dealt with at build time

under 'general' you can choose 'excluded from build' to be 'true' or change the type to describe it accurately (e.g. it won't try and compile things which are 'Text')

Comment: I opened 'properties' of project but I did not find in any menu the option.